# Utilizing a JS lib that has an asm.js component through RoR asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, asm.js

I have a 3rd party JS library that utilizes a generated `*.asm.js file.`  That file and, the JS glue code, and HTML work fine when started up locally through `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`.

I'd like to utilize the same library in RoR.  I've come to learn at a high level what `asm.js` is and what it is used for.  The current error I'm getting is:

```
*.asm.self.js?body=1:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Module is not defined
    at *.asm.self.js?body=1:2
```

where line one is:

```
Module["asm"] = (function(global,env,buffer) {
...
```

I've stashed all the js files in the `vendor/assets/javascripts`.

It is worth noting that the library also comes with a `*.mem` and `*.data` files, which turns out need to be placed in the `public` directory, otherwise the js that uses them appears not to be able to access them if they're sitting alongside the js.

I'm interested to know if anyone has gotten a library that utilizes a generated `asm.js` file to work within RoR, and if so, what are the necessary steps.